# Не получается установить собственное android приложение через apk файл

Tags: java, android

Всем здравствуйте!
Использую android studio, собственно, через него и собирал apk.
При установке приложения на **Android 9.1 Oreo** *Устройство honor 9 lite* возникает неизвестная ошибка - "Приложение не установлено" и всё, кажется, больше никаких признаков, никакой информации о самой ошибке нету.

Я делал:

1. Перезагружал устройство
2. "Перескачивал" apk файл
3. Отключал Google Play защиту (да, он у меня еще есть, так как телефон был куплен где-то 2-4 года назад)
4. Ну и прочее, пробовал почистить файловый менеджер от кэша (так в интернете предлагали), отключал и снова включал установку из незвестных источников как для файлового менеджера, так и для chrome

Теперь о самом приложении, вот файл AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.proj.snackbar">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Snackbar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Минимальная версия SDK для использования этого приложения - 23

Но на всякий оставлю здесь еще builde.gradle:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.proj.snackbar"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- 
rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Само приложение довольно простенькое и, как уже стало понятно по названию, используется для проверки знаний в теме "всплывающих окон" :) Вот сам код из MainActivity

```
package com.zhenya.snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void clickButton(View view) {
    Snackbar.make(view, "hi", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

И также, вдруг понадобится, сам activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="#FF5722"
    android:onClick="clickButton"
    android:text="@string/butt"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:cornerRadius="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Приложение запускал в AVD на Nexus 5 с версией Android 7.1.1, там всё работает отлично. В чем по-вашему мнению может быть ошибка?)

P.S так как это не первое мое приложение, до этого они работали, вернее, устанавливались на этот же телефон, никакие настройки не менял, то есть как прошлые проекты, так и этот точно так же собирался студией по дефолту

UPD: еще хочу сказать, что старые apk по прежнему еще ставятся

Answer (score 1):

Дебаженную версию пытаешься установить? Попробуй через Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK(s). После в папке проекта: app/build/outputs/apk/debug будет app-debug.apk, который должен установиться.

[image: Скрин]

Comment: угу, именно так и делал

Comment: @USER1111, а если запустить дебагом но не на эмуляторе, а на собственном девайсе? Чтоб студия установила через adb. Пробовал?

Comment: Сейчас ничего не понял)) ты про подключение телефона через usb? Если так, то нет, не пробовал)

Comment: @USER1111, да, подключи телефон по шнуру к ПК на котором студия, после этого, выбери в списке вместо эмулятора свой телефон, и нажми на запуск, всё так-же как и с эмулятором, но запустится на твоём телефоне. Перед всем этим включи отладку по USB в меню разработчика.

Comment: Странно, но через отладку всё работает, если удалить приложение, а потом установить через apk , то опять не рботает :(

Comment: вот всё красное,что было в run при запуске приложения E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@437185c
        E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@8099765
        E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
        E/: [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]

Comment: @USER1111, тогда попробуй релизный билд, с подписью, должно сработать

Comment: У меня был случай, когда APK криво студией собиралось. Попробуйте почистить проект, сделать InvalidateCache&Restart студии с последующей пересборкой APK. В моём случае были явные отличия в размере APK файла. С 3-его раза собралось правильно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, походу в этом и была причина, я пересобрал тогда apk (тоже по размерам отличался) и перекинул по usb на телефон, и всё заработало, только теперь беспокоят те ошибки, которые были обнаружены во время отладки))